# Natural Logic Inference

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I've been trying to use the Natural Logic Inference component (Naturalli) packaged with Stanford CoreNLP 3.5.2 to extract relation triples...however upon creating a new OpenIE instance I get the following exception:

```
Could not load affinity model at edu/stanford/nlp/naturalli/: Could not find a part of the path '...\edu\stanford\nlp\naturalli\pp.tab.gz'
```

I tried searching for the pp.tab.gz file on the web but I couldn't find it. Then I tried to get around by disabling the affinity:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("ignoreaffinity", true);
OpenIE ie = new OpenIE(props);
```

But then I started getting this following exception:

```
Could not load clause splitter model at edu/stanford/nlp/naturalli/clauseSplitterModel.ser.gz: Unable to resolve "edu/stanford/nlp/naturalli/clauseSplitterModel.ser.gz" as either class path, filename or URL
```

Same issue with this file...I couldn't find it anywhere.
Any help regarding how to solve these issues is greatly appreciated! Thanks for everyone in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was recently put up, there are some downloads available here:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.shtml

I would recommend using the jars pointed to there instead of the Stanford CoreNLP 3.5.2 release.

Comment: Thanks!! I couldn't find them anywhere!

Comment: You can also use the [GitHub version of the CoreNLP code](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP), along with the current models file: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar . I'll add a link to the project from the StanfordNLP home page in a bit :).

Comment: Thanks!! I really appreciate your feedback! And I really like your framework!!